# blender 3.1 stabilize stroke hotkey?

Tags: shortcut

In version 2.8 it seemed to me that the "stabilize stroke" could be accessed with a hotkey but I'm not sure, in this version 3.1 can a hotkey be configured for "Stabilize Stroke"?, I tried right clicking as before but in the The context menu that opens no longer shows the option "Add Schortcut", is there any other way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version **3.1**, this **tool_settings.image_paint.brush.use_smooth_stroke** already exists but when I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, brush tool **Smooth** is selected.

I solved it by changing in **3dView/Sculpt/Sculpt(Global)/Brush Select**, from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, and now <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to activate **Stabilize Stroke** worked. (in Sculpt mode).

Comment: yes thats exactly the issue i mentioned in the bug report https://developer.blender.org/T88115 and changing the shortcut is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time searching the *Preferences* but i couldn't find anything related to the *Stabilize Stroke* property. As a matter of fact, i couldn't find anything related to Texture Painting. But i found the shortcut by accident which is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to toggle the *Stabilize Stroke* property while in Texture Paint mode. Please also note that there is a known issue of this shortcut in this [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T88115)

Answer (score 0):

Open menu *Edit* ⇾ *Preferences* ⇾ *KeyMap*

Then find keymap *3D View* ⇾ *Image Paint* ⇾ *Image Paint (Global)*

Find the row item *Context Toggle* with `Shift S` shortcut. You can change it here:

[image]

If you don't have a context toggle with *use_smooth_stroke*, you can add a shortcut by clicking the *Add New* button. Then expand the newly created row item and replace the keyword `none` with `wm.context_toggle` and input `tool_settings.image_paint.brush.use_smooth_stroke` in Context attributes.

Comment: Oh that's why i didn't find anything coz they used another term "Context Toggle"

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie `Context toggle` is an operator, `use_smooth_stroke` is a property. You can't run property but operator to manipulate property.